# TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given) Python

Tags: python

I'm making app that will comunicate with microcontroller via UART and I encountered one problem. In function `connectBtnHandler` I'm creating `bh` object and when I'm calling this function it gives me error

```
File "motionPyCfg.py", line 82, in connectBtnHandler
    bh = boardHandler('/dev/ttyUSB0', 19200)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

My code:

```
def __init__(self, port, baudRate):
    self.ser = serial.Serial(port, baudrate = baudRate, parity = serial.PARITY_EVEN, 
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS)
```

This is constructor of `boardHandler`, class from witch I'm creating `bh` object. As you can see there are 2 parameters but I'm still getting error that I'm giving 3 parameters.

```
def connectBtnHandler(self, event):  # wxGlade: MyFrame.<event_handler>
    port = str(self.portCombo.GetValue())
    baudrate = int(self.baudCombo.GetValue())
    print baudrate
    print port
    bh = boardHandler(port, baudrate)
    self.infoText.AppendText("Connected to: " + port + "\n")
    event.Skip()
```

This is function in witch I'm creating `bh` object.

Comment: Is the class and the function connectBtnHandler in the same script?

Comment: Did you define another `__init__` function after that one?

Comment: `3 given` includes the `self` argument

Comment: Why does you error message show constants while your code shows variables? Could it be that you are actually running a different (older) version of the script than you think?

Comment: ( tobias_k) Sorry abouth the/variable constants. I get the same error with constants. ( tobias_k) And I'm not defining another __init__ function after. (Anand S Kumar) Function is is the same script.

Comment: So, did you put in constants for the variables and try to run it again? That's not what I asked. Does the error mesage show constants _even though_ you are using variables in your code? If so, you are running different code. Please try to add some print statement to make 110% sure that you are running the right code.

Comment: Is `bh.__init__.__func__ is boardHandler.__init__.__func__` ?

Comment: As the other comments already show: there's confusion on wrong or missing code provided. This question is useless to others, it should be closed or even deleted.